# Firebase create at timestamp

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In firebase, once you've created several rows of your DB, is there a way that you can query the created at timestamp of a "row" based on the "id". I didn't explicitly store a timestamp and didn't know if there was a method that you could get that back from a query.

**Is is a part of the meta data?**

Comment: Please show us your database structure and the the code you've tried to query

Comment: A timestamp is not part of a database write by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set timestamp to your firebase object while saving.

```
messageNode {
   'postedOn': Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
}
```

this timestamp you can make use of while querying
[Query Firebase data using timestamps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39168779/query-firebase-data-using-timestamps)

Comment: Thanks I know that I can explicitly add a time stamp, I just didn't' know if Firebase was keeping one on an insert that we could go back and query if we hadn't stored it from the start.

Comment: This worked well for me. @rijin, do you know anything of Firebase's default server timestamp?

Answer (score 3):

This question is about the firebase realtime database.
If you want to deal with firestore, you may achieve the same result by the following way:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

messageNode {
  'postedOn': admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
}
```

[reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldValue#.serverTimestamp)

Comment: The question, and accepted answer, are about firebase realtime database. It looks like your answer is about firestore. If you really think this answer belongs here it might be best to make it clear in your answer that this is for firestore and not the realtime database.

Comment: @AndréKool, you're right, thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

The correct code to include the timestamp seems to be

```
created: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
```